# How do I get QGIS to draw the rotated symbols on my map?

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts, qgis-3

I'm working on QGIS 3.2. In my'normal' window I've managed to rotate symbols, so that three attributes now make up three parts of a pie chart. But in the Print Layout composer these rotated symbols are put on top of each other. This results in the top third of the pie being visible, but the other two barely.

How do I get the Print Layout to display the three symbols as a pie chart?

Comment: Are you using the Diagrams tab in the layer properties?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Thanks for your response. No, I'm not using the diagrams tab. Would that work better in the print layout? If so, is there a handy way to get the colourbars I'm using now into the diagrams' code? (each part of the pie has a colourbar with different classes)

Comment: I was asking because I'm not sure what you want as a result. Do you show a pie chart for every feature like in this: https://imgur.com/a/TTViyq8 or is it something different? The screenshot is a random example I made in 2 minutes using 3 fields on this polygon layer but also scaling the symbol according to another field. If what you try to achieve is similar, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: No, this is not what I've been trying to do. Sorry, I have nowhere to upload pictures, so don't know how to show you what I mean. Basically, I have 3 parts, each 1/3 of the total size. I want the colour of each part to represent values (classified) of three different columns in the attribute table. E.g. one for nitrate concentration, one for ammonium and one for turbidity.

Comment: I don't understand how your chart is supposed to work. Is it the legend for the classified values in your map? If so, why does it need to be in the main (normal) window? Why not just create it in the map composer?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, no that's not it. not being able to show you a picture makes it impossible to show you better. So let's just leave this unresolved. Thanks for your suggestions and help though!

Comment: You can upload an image to the question, no need to have a location to put an image